# Where to save images within AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I was discussing with friends about the best way to store files in amazon.

I believed that an s3 bucket was the best way to save static files as images from a website.

But friends said that it is not the best way to work with s3 because of the high cost of having this image requested many times.

I need to know the best place to save images that will be rendered inside my site (which is inside an EC2 instance).

Could someone clarify this doubt? Saving images inside the S3 in sites that have many requests is expensive?

Comment: Amazon s3 edge is the best option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For storing static files like images [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) is one of the best option.

S3 is one of the cheapest cloud storage, you won't be charged for the number of times it's read, only amount of outbound traffic will bbe charged. For get requuest/put request there is also a charge, but you shouldn't need it as per my understanding, you can clarify your use case more precisely. You  can also calculate the price [here](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).

Find all the storage services AWS offers here: https://aws.amazon.com/products/storage/

Comment: Glacier is not at all appropriate for serving static content -- it's intended for cold storage (hence the name), and allows for neither public nor real-time access to stored data. I've removed it from your answer, as the rest of your answer is largely correct.

Comment: yeah, Glacier is more appropriate for data archive, not useful for this use case.